# Child route is loaded but not rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It is a simple site taking use of react-router for "code splitting". I uploaded the source code here : https://github.com/wangjia184/log_viewer

In [app.js](https://github.com/wangjia184/log_viewer/blob/master/app.js), the following route is defined.

```
const rootRoute = {
  component: 'div',
  childRoutes: [ {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./routes/setting/view'),
    childRoutes: [
      require('./routes/indices')
    ]
  }]
};
```

In [routes/setting/view](https://github.com/wangjia184/log_viewer/blob/master/routes/setting/view.js), there is a link redirecting the user to `/indices`

```
class SettingUI extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Link to={`/indices`} activeClassName="active">Go to /indices</Link>
  }
};
```

When I click this link, the url in address bar changes, `getComponent` within [routes/indices/index.js](https://github.com/wangjia184/log_viewer/blob/master/routes/indices/index.js) method is fired.

```
module.exports = {
  path: 'indices',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./view'));
    })
  }
}
```

[routes/indices/view.js](https://github.com/wangjia184/log_viewer/blob/master/routes/indices/view.js) is supposed to be rendered.

```
class IndicesUI extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('componentWillMount()');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount()');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount()');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render()');
    return <h2>IndicesUI</h2>
  }
}

console.log('IndicesUI is loaded');

module.exports = IndicesUI;
```

But in fact, the component is loaded but not rendered. There is no error in web browser console but display is not updated.
[image]

Directory `/build` contains the final files generated by webpack.

I appreciate any one who look into this.

**UPDATED**:

```
const loadContainerAsync = bundle => (location, cb) => {
  bundle(component => {
    cb(null, component);
  });
};

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={DefaultView}>
        <Route path="indices" getComponent={loadContainerAsync(require('bundle?lazy!./components/indices'))} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your app.js like below mentioned and it's working on my end

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, NotFoundRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

export default class Root extends Component {

  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    var Data=[{path:"/",component:'./routes/setting/view'},{path:"indices",component:'./routes/indices/view'}];
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        {Object.keys(Data).map(function(m){
          return(
            <Route path={Data[m].path} component={require(Data[m].component)} />
          )
        })}
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Root history={hashHistory} /> , document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Comment: Yep, static route work but that is not what I want. What I want is lazy load of the child route.  I was coding basing on example from https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps

Comment: Thanks,  maybe I don't explain the question clearly.  I expect the component to be lazy loaded till user is redirected to there. I updated the question and found a solution.